# Assembly language: counter loop

Tags: assembly, counter, x86-16

I have written an assembly code that includes:

```
    XOR BL,BL
    MOV CX,0 
TOP: 
    INC BL,1
    MOV AH,2 
    MOV DL, BL 
    INT 21H
    LOOP TOP
```

The loop is executed a really large number of times (more than 10,000 for sure). What could be the possible reason behind the loop execution of such a high time? I am very new in assembly language and found nothing efficient to my code related to CX=0. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Single-stepping through your code in a debugger watching registers would have caught this.  You'd see CX=0xFFFF after the first iteration, which would prompt you to go look it up in the manual and find out that it doesn't check before decrementing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your counter `cx` was not properly initialized. The instruction `loop` does two things:

```
dec cx            ;◄■■■ DECREASE THE COUNTER.
jnz label         ;◄■■■ IF COUNTER IS NOT ZERO, JUMP TO LABEL TO REPEAT.
```

In your code the counter `cx` was initialized as zero, so, when the `loop` instruction executes, it does `cx - 1`, which is `0 - 1`, so `cx` becomes `0ffffh` and your loop will repeat `0ffffh` times.

Move another value to your counter `cx`, for example, `mov cx, 10`, so your loop will repeat 10 times.

Comment: Thanks Joes for explaining in detail

Answer (score 1):

The Intel `loop` instruction decrements the CX register first and then checks for zero condition.

Set CX to 1 prior to `TOP:` to test.